# Prove that if $\sum |a_n|^2$ converges then $ \sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $ \{a_n\}\in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that if $\sum |a_n|^2$ converges than $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges.

Note that this problem is taken from the first chapter on series of a calculus book, so it should be solvable with very basic tools (e.g. the only convergence test introduced was the comparison test and nothing about absolute convergence is assumed).

I have tried a few thing but nothing worked. Could you give me a hint on how to approach the problem?

Comment: (Note that the other question talks about $\mathbb{R}$, but there's nothing there that doesn't really apply here.  Also, this has to be one of the most-duplicated analysis questions on this site - I count at least a half-dozen different instances...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other two answers, [Robert Z's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911212/75808) and [anonymus'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911218/75808), use [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) to establish (absolute) convergence of the series with general term $\frac{a_n}{n}$. As an alternative, one can use the [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality:$^{(\ast)}$ indeed, 
$$
\frac{\lvert a_n\rvert }{n} = \sqrt{\frac{\lvert a_n\rvert^2 }{n^2}}
\leq \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}{2}
$$
for all $n\geq 1$. It only remains to  conclude by theorems of comparison.

---

${}^{(\ast)}$ *"Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means."*

Answer (score 9):

Use [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality and the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent:
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{|a_n|}{n}\right)^2\leq \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n|^2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}<+\infty$$
Hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ is absolutely convergent and therefore also convergent.

Answer (score 4):

With Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that $\sum_n 1/n^2 < \infty$, the result follows.